# openssl ssl_connect blocks forever - how to set timeout?

Tags: ssl, openssl

when server written in openssl is'nt calling SSL_accept, client's SSL_connect blocks forever.
There are some timeout functions in openssl -SSL_CTX_set_timeout , SSL_SESSION_set_timeout but these have no effect on SSL_connect.

Is there really no way of setting timeout for SSL_connect when e.g. ssl server is buggy and goes into loop before doing SSL handshake?

Answer (score 13):

The OpenSSL Library gives you the maximum flexibility in terms of handling socket related issues. The `SSL_connect` blocks in your case because you must be using it with a blocking socket. Please use it with a non-blocking socket, in which case it will return with a -1. If you call `SSL_get_error` function which will give you `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` error depending on when the tcp recv or send is unable to complete the operation respectively.

When `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`/`SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` is obtained, you must call select function by passing the socket to appropriate `fd_set` and a timeout. If the select times out, you can consider your `SSL_connect` to have timed out.

**Note:**  The `SSL_SESSION_set_timeout` is used for setting session timeout values which are linked to SSL resumption. They have nothing to do with timing out a connection.

The below links should help you (especially the second link, Section 6 which talks about Multiplexed I/O):

- [Part 1](https://github.com/smbutton/DataCommProject/blob/master/openssl-examples-20020110/openssl-examples-20020110/part1.pdf)
- [Part 2](https://github.com/smbutton/DataCommProject/blob/master/openssl-examples-20020110/openssl-examples-20020110/part2.pdf)

Comment: :( linked resource moved

Comment: Here are some other links to those PDFs: [part1](http://vanets.vuse.vanderbilt.edu/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=resource:part1.pdf), and [part2](http://vanets.vuse.vanderbilt.edu/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=resource:part2.pdf).  Hope this helps!