# Socket timeout in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, timeout

I have the following code basically listening on port 443 using SSL (copying from another question here):
[How can I get info on an already closed SSL connection that caused an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787335/how-can-i-get-info-on-an-already-closed-ssl-connection-that-caused-an-error)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "socket"
require "openssl"

cert_path = Dir["/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"].first
key_path = Dir["/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"].first
chain_path = Dir["/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem"].first
context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new( File.read( cert_path ))
context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new( File.read( key_path ))
context.extra_chain_cert = [ OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new( File.read( chain_path )) ]

port = 443
t = TCPServer.new( port )
s = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new( t, context )

begin
    r = s.accept
rescue
    # get client ip here
    p r.methods.sort
end
```

Client sends info through a post request to the server and the code runs over 35 minutes here and then the result about the operation is sent back to client. The call is a blocking one and I need it this way.

The problem is that if the code runs over 30 minutes then the server code cannot send back the info. If under 30 min, then it can without any problem. Operating system is Linux (Ubuntu 18 x64) and I keep checking the sockets with netstat and they are there till the end of the procedure with ESTABLISHED status, no suspicious things here.

I assume it has to do something with some kind of system timeout value. From the post call I set all timeout that I can to the HTTP object (open, read, keep_alive, continue, write, ssl), still no luck, the result does not get back to the client.

Could you give me any hints about what setting could cause this issue? Thank you.

---

Edit:

I've tested my code without the SSL layer and there is no timeout issue. I also tested the timeout and ssl_timeout properties of the Contex object above without any result. Still looking for a setting to avoid the problem caused by timeout in the SSL layer.

---

Edit:

I've tested the call through SSL using Python3 on client side instead of Ruby (2.6) and the same issue happens. Server side has Ruby. So it is either the Ruby implementaion of OpenSSL that causes it or OpenSSL itself.

---

Edit:

New progress: I noticed that initiating the procedure through SSL on the same host does not have a problem so I'm thinking that my hosting provider might put some limit to the longer connections.

---

Edit:

Solved. I would have never thought so but my ISP has something to do with the time limitation issues of my longer connections.

Comment: Experimenting with "socket.setsockopt( Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_RCVTIMEO, timeval )" without any success

Comment: Try `set_sock_opt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_KEEPALIVE, true)` to keep the connection alive.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Unfortunately it does not work. The connection stays established on client side and closes on server side. How can this be? I'll take a try by using your suggestion and experimenting with the timeout settings of the http object on client side.

Comment: No success so far.

Comment: When you say "the server code cannot send back the info" what do you mean exactly? Error, crash, ... ?

Comment: So actually what happens is the following: when the client connects and sends data, the code on server side runs, and I also store the socket object - then the running finishes, I send back the info with socket.print( result ) command, and the socket closes on server side but remains open on client side. So no error message, nothing. Whats interesting is that the local port on client and server side match up. netstat also reports the sockets being open during the procedure. This is my problem that I am stuck on figuring out how to continue tracking the issue. Thx.

Comment: (Edit: and as I said, it works with run time less than approx. 30 min, and has problem with above 30 )

Comment: Also looking for kernel settings in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp* but cannot find any relevant one with values similar to 1500 or 1800 (the 30 min limit)

Comment: If there's some code that you're using, even if you've directly lifted it line for line from another question, you must include that code directly in your post because the linked question can be changed or removed in the future.

Comment: I've been testing the client server communication through sockets in Ruby without SSL and I see no time limit. So I'm getting to think now that it has something to do with the SSL layer for which I use OpenSSL just like in the code on the link at the top. Anyone has any experience with OpenSSL and time limits in MRI Ruby? Wondering to switch to stunnel instead.

Comment: @horv77 have you tried another programming language? Maybe it's not related to Ruby at all.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853702/3784008) led to [this](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/Session.html#method-i-timeout-3D). Maybe there's something in there that can help.

Comment: I do not have a SSL::Session object. I also tried to set the timeout and ssl_timeout property of the SSL:Contex object without any result. Now I'm testing the whole process without the SSL layer and see how it pans out. Expecting to finish with it in an hour or so. If it will work, then the SSL layer forces a timeout on my connection. If so, then I'll try to setup an stunnel for letsencrypt cert. I'll get back with the result.

Comment: @Stefan Ruby does not any problem with my code without the SSL layer when using a simple TCP server and client process.

Comment: So I've checked the whole process without the SSL layer and it works, no timeout issue. I've been very careful with the experiment to remove only the SSL sayer and leave everything untouched that had produced problem before. Now it is clear that the SSL has problem with connections over 30 minutes. Now I look into either finding a setting for this, or settting up stunnel and run a test with that.

Comment: @horv77 great you solved it. When you said “client” and “server”, I thought these were two applications running on the same machine. (or at least on the same network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested and my ISP has something to do with the time limitation issues of my longer connections.