# How to make SSL_connect to timeout?

Tags: openssl, timeout, libssl

How to make the function to the function SSL_connect (of a libssl) to timeout after a defined amount of time ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [openssl ssl\_connect blocks forever - how to set timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835203/openssl-ssl-connect-blocks-forever-how-to-set-timeout)